# Merge two Matrices without Duplicates

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two matrices, for example:

```
data1 = {{"c1", "c2", "c3"}, {2, 5, 3}, {54, 2, 3}, {11, 2, 10}, {3, 
5, 7}};
```

and

```
data2 = {{"c1", "c2", "c3"}, {11, 2, 10}, {3, 5, 7}, {2, 5, 3}, {54, 
2, 3}, {3, 1, 4}, {5, 2, 3}};
```

I would like to merge these two matrices in a way that there is only one copy of the overlapping rows. This should lead to:

```
merged = {{"c1", "c2", "c3"}, {2, 5, 3}, {54, 2, 3}, {11, 2, 10}, {3, 
5, 7}, {2, 5, 3}, {54, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 4}, {5, 2, 3}};
```

I'm looking for a procedure which works also for examples which don't overlapp.

Comment: Does `Union[data1,data2]` work for you or is the order of the elements important?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
{data1, Rest@data2} /. {{a__, b__}, {b__, c__}} :> {a, b, c}
(* {{"c1", "c2", "c3"}, {2, 5, 3}, {54, 2, 3}, {11, 2, 10}, 
      {3, 5, 7}, {2, 5, 3}, {54, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 4}, {5, 2, 3}} *)
```

Comment: Forgetting about the header row for a moment, `a___` and `c___` would probably be better here, in case one of the lists is fully contained within the other.

Comment: Thx, that's as elegant as it can get. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
DeleteDuplicates@Join[data1, data2]

{{"c1", "c2", "c3"}, {2, 5, 3}, {54, 2, 3}, {11, 2, 10}, {3, 5,7}, {3, 1, 4}, {5, 2, 3}}
```

I am not sure what you are looking for, because you left some duplicates in the merged list

Comment: I think the left-over duplicates are deliberate. As I understand it the idea is to remove just the elements at the beginning of `data2` which are at the end of `data1`, like stitching together multiple images to make a panorama.

Comment: The problem is that I just want to get rid of the overlapp. There may exist duplicates within one of the matrices as well.

Comment: @SimonWoods You should put that quote into the question. Much more clear now :)